# amazon s3 per hour billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a question on how Amazon bills for storing in s3.

According to their pricing page, they bill for a period of 1 month. But what if I upload a file on day one and then I delete the file (Versioning not enabled) on day two, Will I still be charged a standard rate specified for the entire month, or will there be some cost reduction.

If its the case, do we have any official document from amazon to that effect, as their pricing page has only per-month-pricing details.

If its not the case, then is there a use in setting life cycle policy to delete the files in 1 day. Since they have such policy, one would assume, it would reduce the price as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Understanding your AWS billing and usage reports for Amazon S3 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/aws-usage-report-understand.html):

> The volume of storage that we bill you for each month is based on the **average amount of storage you used throughout the month**. You are billed for all of the object data and metadata stored in buckets that you created under your AWS account.
>
> **We measure your storage usage in `TimedStorage-ByteHrs`, which are totaled up at the end of the month to generate your monthly charges.** The usage report reports your storage usage in `byte-hours` and the billing reports report storage usage in `GB-months`. To correlate your usage report to your billing reports, you need to convert byte-hours into GB-months.
>
> For example, if you store 100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes) of STANDARD Amazon S3 storage data in your bucket for the first 15 days in March, and 100 TB (109,951,162,777,600 bytes) of STANDARD Amazon S3 storage data for the final 16 days in March, you will have used 42,259,901,212,262,400 byte-hours.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for the help. I request you to see if by any chance in your memory you have a link of official documentation. Would be of great help....

Comment: Found a reference for you. Updated answer.